# Detect Changes of control inside another user Control using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an issue to detect changes of text control inside my user control which called with the page 
Info: I want to call function of detect changes from the page not from the user control
I already have tried some tries

```
$('#' + '<%:this.usrCtrl.ClientID%>' + '_myText').change(function () {
    // my code should be here
});
```

usrCtrl should be my user control name, myText is the text inside the user control.
Also tried `focusout` trigger with no result back, any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If `myText` is a TextBox inside user control `usrCtrl`, you need to use FindControl to locate the element inside the Control and get it's ClientID.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%= usrCtrl.FindControl("myText").ClientID %>').change(function () {
        alert('Changed');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but simply its same as mine with more use for code rather than Jquery methods, unfortunately it doesn't work neither...